# Why I get Apple Push Notification with launchOption dictionary nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am sending push notifications from server and if the the app is running in background, notification arrives and tapping it calls the didReceiveRemoteNotification().

But when I kill my app(swiping up the app after double pressing home button, notification arrives but tapping the notification only direct the screen to app home. I already coded in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions() like below.

```
 if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary* dictionary = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (dictionary != nil)
        {

            NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);

            NSString *strVendId=[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"payload.vendor_id"];

            UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

            VenderDetailController *vDetail=[mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"venDetail"];
            vDetail.strVendorId=strVendId;
            [navController pushViewController:vDetail animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

There is no way I can debug this as app gets killed. Maybe I get nil dictionary I can't tell. I even tried to remove launchOption nil condition, still no help.

I am using objective C and this problem is driving me crazy.

Comment: can you log the launchOptions and tell the values

Comment: How can I achieve that if I kill the app, xcode project stops. So how can I log whats in the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check the logs in device logs to confirm if the Dictionary is nil or not. For checking the logs when the app is terminated. Go to Window -> Devices, then select your device, after that tap on the arrow icon in bottom left as shown in the image below. You will be able to see all the logs even if you are not running the app from Xcode :[image]
[image]

Log the dictionary you are getting, it will help in debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
NSDictionary *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chandan005's solution to see the debugging console or you can show the `dictionary` content using UIAlertView inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions` to check whether you get correct remote notification payload or not.